# ASP.NET MVC slideshow - different views

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a Health & Monitoring application which has several dashboards. Working on showing on all dashboards one by one as a slideshow. So that we know the health of the system without manual intervention.

This is what I did. Developed a view for slideshow Slideshow.cshtml and which has jquery code to connect to controllers and those controllers return partial views and partial views has code to connect to the server and display the data. So partial views are different dashboards. Tried to put it as simple as possible with the code. Sorry for the lengthy code.

I see dashboards are not displaying any data after sometime. I am looking for the suggestions and best practices and how to do it in a better way. are there any open source plug-ins we can use?

**Slideshow.cshtml**

```
<div id="partialContainer"></div>

$(function () {
    getData();
    setInterval(getData, 60000); // Iterate all pages 20 sec each page       
});

function getData() {      

    getData1();

    setTimeout(getData2, 20000); //20 Sec

    setTimeout(getData3, 40000); //20 Sec          
}

function getData1() {
    $.ajax({            
        url: "@Url.Action("GetData1", "Dashboard")",
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#partialContainer').html(data);
        }
    });
}

function getData2() {
    $.ajax({            
        url: "@Url.Action("GetData2", "Dashboard")",
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#partialContainer').html(data);
        }
    });
}

function getData3() {
    $.ajax({            
        url: "@Url.Action("GetData3", "Dashboard")",
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#partialContainer').html(data);
        }
    });
}

****Controller:****
 public class DashboardController : Controller
 {      
    public ActionResult GetData1()
    {
        return PartialView("_Data1");
    }
    public ActionResult GetData2()
    {
        return PartialView("_Data2");
    }
    public ActionResult GetData3()
    {
        return PartialView("_Data3");
    }
  }

 ****One of the Dashboards(partial view): _Data1.cshtml****
 <script>

  $.ajaxSetup({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses */
    cache: false
  });

 getDataP1();    

  function getDataP1() {

    $("#tblErrors > tbody").html("");

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetSummary", "Dashboard")',
        data: {},
        type: 'GET',
        error: function () {

        },
        success: function (res) {
            for (i = 0; i < res.Errors.length; i++) {

                var data = res.Errors[i];               

                var rowClass = 'alt';
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                    rowClass = '';

                var row = "<tr class='" + rowClass + "'>";

                //Appn Name
                row = row + "<td>" + data.AppnName + "</td>";

                //Application Type
                row = row + "<td>" + data.ApplicationType + "</td>";

                //Status
                row = row + "<td>" + data.Status + "</td>";

                row = row + "</tr>";

                $("#tblErrors").append(row);
            }
            $("label[for='refreshTime']").html(res.LastRefreshTime);
          }
      });
    }

  </script>
```

Comment: you have `getData` in main view and also in the partial view in **global scope**.. I think this would be causing the issue.. Coming to best practices the mere basic is **Naming convention** of your methods. Your method name must give a high level of what it does.. For EG: `GetTopCostPatientsHealthInfo` , `GetHighRiskPatientsHealthInfo` etc etc

Comment: Actual methods names are different. This is just a copy/paste errors while posting this question. I didn't want to put actual methods/code and confuse everyone with too much code here.. I have tried to put it in simplest way.

Comment: My question is not about naming the methods just in case I confused you. I have named them meaningfully. My question is more of how to solve this problem(slideshow) and any issues with the approach I am following.

Comment: The first line of my comment was supposed to direct you to the solution for the problem.. Also check your console window for errors.. Let me know what you find.